# Merging a column of sequential numbers in multiple .csv files into single .csv file

Tags: text-processing

I am on Linux/Centos7. I have multiple csv files I want to merge, I am using this command to merge.

```
cat *csv > all.csv
```

But the first column contain a sequential number that needs to be merged and renumbered in sequential order.

```
==> 1.csv <==
1,bob,date,body
2,joe,date,body
3,ann,date,body

==> 2.csv <==
1,lisa,date,body
2,paul,date,body
3,mike,date,body
```

I would like the result to renumber the first column to be like this

```
==> output.csv <==
1,bob,date,body
2,joe,date,body
3,ann,date,body
4,lisa,date,body
5,paul,date,body
6,mike,date,body
```

When I do a regular merge I have this, And if I can renumber this merged file that would work too.

```
1,bob,date,body
2,joe,date,body
3,ann,date,body
1,lisa,date,body
2,paul,date,body
3,mike,date,body
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will do what you want

```
cat *.csv | cut  --complement -d',' -f1 |sed -e 's/^/,/' |nl |sed -e "s/ //g"|sed -e "s/\\t//g" >all.csv
```

`cut  --complement -d',' -f1` will caut the first column and yo will obtain

```
bob,date,body
joe,date,body
ann,date,body
lisa,date,body
paul,date,body
mike,date,body
```

`sed -e 's/^/,/'` will add a , in the beginning of each line

```
,bob,date,body
,joe,date,body
```

nl will add the number in the beginning of each line

```
 1  ,bob,date,body
 2  ,joe,date,body
 3  ,ann,date,body
 4  ,lisa,date,body
```

and `sed -e "s/ //g"|sed -e "s/\\t//g"` will delete the spaces between the number and the comma (,)